# If auto generate alphanumeric data not exist then create new and insert with php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am developing a site using Php, where I use PDO for database.
Now I am creating a random alphanumeric data(using JavaScript) which I will insert in database. But if anytime the data match the existing data then I want to create new and insert.
What I want is to insert a unique alphanumeric data each time.
I have tried by fetching the record from database and then check with the new generated data, if data not exist then insert, else create new one and check again.
Is there any option by which it will be easier.
Suppose Database table name is User and columns are id(auto increment), name and reg_key(alphanumeric).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mysql uuid function?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid